# Conflicting python versions - Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark cluster with 1 driver and 2 worker nodes. I am trying to run a pyspark snippet on this cluster with the driver having python 3.9. However, the driver and worker nodes have other versions of python3 installed additionally. This is giving me a `RuntimeError`.

```
RuntimeError: Python in worker has different version 3.6 than that in driver 3.9, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions. Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.
```

I tried setting the environment variables for `PYSPARK_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` on the driver and workers.

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/location/bin/python3.9
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/location/bin/python3.9
```

Even after doing this, I get the same error.

Comment: Are your export commands in `spark-env.sh` file? And you restarted the workers?

Comment: No the export commands were executed in the terminals of my workers and driver. I havent restarted the workers.

Comment: Exports only work for subsequently ran processes afterwards. You need to place those settings in Spark config files, then restart them